# MongoDB: update dictionary in document

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, upsert

I have a MongoDB document that saves occurrences of some things in a dictionary:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "occurrences" : {
    "1" : 1,
    "2" : 5,
    "17" : 1,
    "35" : 4
  }
}
```

I now want to add or update some entries, for example add a "12:3" to the occurrences, or update the number of occurrences of "17" to 2, so let's say as an example I want to add {"12":3} and {"17":2} to this dictionary.
It is driving me crazy because I simply can not get it to work. I could use arrays and all that, but I would really like to have it in this particular design. Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried so many different things with $set and $each and so on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from [mongoDb website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) look at "Set Fields in Embedded Documents"

```
To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.
For the document matching the criteria _id equal to 100, the following
operation updates the make field in the details document:


db.products.update(
{ _id: 100 },
{ $set: { "details.make": "zzz" } })
```

in your case

```
db.collection.update(
     {_id:ObjectId("1")},
     { $set: { "occurrences.12": "3", "occurrences.17": "2" }})
```

Comment: Hey, I should have stated that I found this, however, needing to add this "occurrences." in front of every occurrence is super unhandy. Maybe there is a simpler way? By the way, I will eventually use the Java Driver for MongoDB.

Comment: there is no other way, at lease not from native MongoDB side as far as I'm concerened. this is called the dot notation and this is how mongodb access arrays and embbededd documents.

Comment: A simple tool may help to make it easily. https://gist.github.com/ansvver/76a24038c9ab7b4cec835b3276e44075

Comment: hi the above solution will update/overwrite the existing values. so how to add new dictionary values say    
"occurrences" : {
    "1" : 1,
    "2" : 5,
    "17" : 1,
    "35" : 4,
"40":9  ----> this is new value
  }

Comment: @Devanathan.S - New values will also be added.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function to convert a dictionary to a new dictionary which only updates fields in that dictionary:

```
def convert_2_dict_mongodb(obj):
    result = {}
    for key, val in obj.items():
        if not isinstance(val, dict):
            result[key] = val
            continue

        for sub_key, sub_val in val.items():
            new_key = '{}.{}'.format(key, sub_key)
            result[new_key] = sub_val
            if not isinstance(sub_val, dict):
                continue

            result.update(convert_2_dict_mongodb(result))
            if new_key in result:
                del result[new_key]

    return result
```

Example:

```
abc = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': {
        'x': 1,
        'y': 2,
        'z': {
            'g': 1,
            'h': {
                'e': [1, 2, 3]
            }
        }
    },
    'h': {
        'a': [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

To:

```
{'h.a': [1, 2, 3], 'b.x': 1, 'b.z.h.e': [1, 2, 3], 'b.z.g': 1, 'a': 1, 'b.y': 2}
```