# Adding to an embedded document: to dot, or not to dot

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Tools: mongodb:2.1.3 (Node.js Driver)

**Objective:**

What I set out to learn today is how to add a new property to a nested object in Mongodb **using the native Node.js driver**.

**Problem - To dot, or not to dot, that is the question :**

So far, in Mongodb jargon it sounds like I'm trying to "[add to an embedded document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267519/mongodb-update-dictionary-in-document)".

In the example in the link above the user wanted to update `occurrences` by adding a new "field"(i.e. add {12:3} to `occurrences`)

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "occurrences" : {
    "1" : 1,
    "2" : 5,
    "17" : 1,
    "35" : 4
  }
}
```

And the most popular answer was to do the following(which I assume "findOneAndUpdate" has recently superseded)

```
db.collection.update(
     {_id:ObjectId("1")},
     { $set: { "occurrences.12": "3" }
});
```

Small Note - I removed the other atomic update in the answer for simplicity.

**Question:**

**Would this non-dot solution be an equal alternative to that? Or would it be wrong,different, or have any other underlying consequences to do it this way below?**

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
     {_id:ObjectId("1")},
     { $set: { "occurrences": {"12:3"}}
});
```

Note: I use `findOneAndUpdate` because it appears to be the current equivalent.

Comment: It'd be wrong, because it would set the value of "occurrences" to that object alone. You could probably try it and see for yourself, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like using a JavaScript object:

```
let occurrences = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6};
// add new property
occurrences[12] = 3;

// clobber object
occurrences = {12: 3};
```

Also be aware [that you may not want to embed documents at all](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/) depending upon how you want to structure your data. Sometimes you may want to normalize ... but sometimes you don't.

---

Note that you can also use `updateOne` with the native driver.

Comment: Oh! Looks like $push and $set work a bit different - whereas one one appends, the other overwrites?

Comment: I rationalized $set to be the object operation equivalent of $push(which I assumed was for arrays)